# Space isn't increasing after deleting files on external hdd mac os trash is empty

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive

I deleted files from external hard drive, they are no longer there, trash is empty but space hasn't increased, what do I do?

Comment: What format is the external drive and how did you delete the files (through the Finder, through an application, from the command line)?

Answer (score 2):

Launch the terminal / command line, and replacing 'VolumeName' with the name of your drive type:

`sudo rm -R /Volumes/volumeName/.Trashes`

Each drive has its own hidden .Trash folder, and each user has a folder in that folder. The above will delete all trash folders on that specific drive.